# .htaccess file works with Errors, but not with rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've created a .htaccess file, and can get the server to serve me a custom 404 page. However, when i try and do a re-write, it doesn't work.
The htaccess file is located in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /htaccessTest/index.php /htaccessTest/phpinfo.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /htaccessTest/errors/404_message.php
```

I'm not sure as to why this isn't working. I've checked phpinfo, and under Apache2, it states that mod_rewrite has been loaded.
I'm really stumped here. 
Not sure what's going on!
Any help would be great!

### Update 1

As per what was highlighted below, i found that it still didn't work! I've made some changes, and now all I get is the 404 error message, unless I navigate to the index page.
Here are the changes:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /htaccessTest/errors/404_message.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^htaccessTest/test\.php$ /htaccessTest/phpinfo\.php$ [L,NC]
```

And i access it using the url:

> localhost/htaccessTest/test.php

(ignore the lack of http://, I've removed so that it didn't think it was a link). 

Any further ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer after hacking around with it.

It seems to be the first part of the Rewrite.
There is a difference with the first and second section that I didn't realise, which is that the URL sort of "resets" when using Rewrite.

This is explained easier by giving you the now re-worked example.

Original:

```
RewriteRule ^htaccessTest/test\.php$ /htaccessTest/phpinfo\.php$ [L,NC]
```

New:

```
RewriteRule ^test.php /htaccessTest/phpinfo.php
```

As you can see, the first part references **htaccessTest**. You don't need this part, as the url was "already in" this file structure. Your url being: "localhost/htaccessTest/test.php"

The second part stays roughly the same, I just removed the Regex stuff and the [L,NC]. The [L, NC] will probably come in handy later, but for simplicity sake I removed it.

The result is this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /htaccessTest/errors/404_message.php
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^test.php /htaccessTest/phpinfo.php
```

Thanks for the help guys! (Especially @anubhava)

Answer (score 3):

Try your rule without leading slash:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /htaccessTest/errors/404_message.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^htaccessTest/index\.php$ /htaccessTest/phpinfo.php [L,NC]
```

- Better to use line start/end anchors to avoid matching unexpected text in an URI.
- dot needs to be escaped in a regex which otherwise matches any character.
- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: You should also specifically mention the escaping of `.` that you added as well.  This is important to make sure the rule only matches the single desired URI.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately

Comment: What is filesystem location of above .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava it's located in htdoc files of Xamp. This is located on the C drive.

Comment: So it is: `c:\htdocs` path? And `htaccessTest` is sub directory as `c:\htdocs\htaccessTest`?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\htaccessTest is the file path to the folder. I've tried moving the htaccess file into htdocs, but to no avail.

Comment: Verify whether this `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?